# Validating PDF Form Fields for number characters only

Tags: javascript, validation, pdf

Developing a PDF form that requires field validation. I am using Bluebeam however from what I see so far it works exactly the same as any other PDF form creator.

So I am trying to validate the field for number characters only and accept the value if it is number characters (must also accept text starting with single and multiple 0's). The following was having a guess of what it might have to use.

```
var fld = this.getfield(“Text1”)’
If IsNumeric(“Text1”) == true;
event.value = fld.value
else
alert(“Error message”)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope this helps:

```
var fld = this.getfield(“Text1”).value;
if(fld.match(/^\d+$/)){
event.value = fld.value;}
else{
alert(“Error message”);}
```

Comment: Sorry I think how bluebeam does its data validation is more complicated than this. I have emailed Bluebeam and hopefully I get an answer soon.